# Converting image from numpy array to fastai tensor - memory is too big

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, fast-ai

I am working on a pretrained model with fast.ai. In my first step I used a local image, which I read and the variable type is `vision.image.Image` then. Then I tried to use a image from my webcam with `cv2.Videocapture`. But here my problem appears. Because `frame` is a numpy array, first I need to convert it to a fast.ai tensor with `Image(torch.from_numpy(frame).float())`. But there I get the problem. The error says

> DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate
> 167771750400 bytes

I am wondering why the memory is getting so big by converting. When I use the same image as before, just instead `cv2.imread()` I have the same problem. So I guess the problem is by converting the image to a tensor and not because I use the webcam.

Here is an exapmle for my picture I used before [image]

Any ideas? I appreciate your answers. Thanks.

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *
from fastai.callbacks.hooks import *
from fastai.utils.mem import *
import cv2
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def acc_camvid(input, target):
    target = target.squeeze(1)
    mask = target != void_code
    #print(mask)
    return (input.argmax(dim=1)[mask]==target[mask]).float().mean()

learn=load_learner(pretrained_model)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#frame= cv2.imread(image)
    
_,frame = cap.read()
cap.release()

image = Image(torch.from_numpy(frame).float())
plt.imshow(frame)
  
img = image; img.shape
_,img_hr,b = learn.predict(img)
Image(img_hr).show(figsize=(18,15))
```

Comment: ~168 GB is a LOT of memory, how big was your numpy array (arr.nbytes)?

Comment: yep, that is why I am wondering. The numpy array size is (480, 640, 3) and 921600 bytes -  so just a normal image size.

Comment: Can you share the image? also, try loading image first then model.

Comment: So the original array's `dtype` is only 1 byte (color level). The `torch.from_numpy` makes a tensor that uses the same memory as the underlying array. The `.float()` creates a new tensor where each element is coerced to a `float32`, which is 4 bytes. But the new tensor should still only be 3686400 bytes (~3.69 MB).

Comment: If you're right about the error coming from the tensor creation line, a MWE would have 1) your image uploaded (480x640 should be fine), 2) a line that `imread`s the image, 3) some lines printing the array's size, and finally 4) the tensor creation line. Try such a script and see if it reproduces the error. If it does, edit your post to have the MWE and change the title to point out your array and tensors are way smaller than the 168 GB the Exception claims.

Comment: I found another solution for the problem. Instead of `image = Image(torch.from_numpy(frame).float())` I used `image = Image(pil2tensor(frame, dtype=np.float32).div_(255))`. There was no error and everything worked correctly. But I still dont know, why the other error appears.

Comment: @kHarshit I've added a picture to my post. I took the picture with the same camera, as I want to use right now in the code.

Comment: @BatWannaBe I'm not sure what you mean. What is MWE?
I tried to run only the convertation to tensor and plot this picutre. But then I get a type error."Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float".

Comment: @Ikrss MWE stands for "minimum working example" and basically means a small amount of data and code that other people can use to see the results and errors for themselves. A MWE should be small so it's feasible to quickly copy, test, and read. So in your case, the data would be the image. Your code is actually already fairly small, so I take back my advice about changing that.